# How can I make a copy of a file with a new name that contains the timestamp of the original in the filename?

Tags: linux, bash, unix, scripting

Writing a bash script that will copy a file into a directory where the new copy has the same name, but with the timestamp appended to the filename (prior to the extension).

How can I achieve this?

Comment: By "timestamp" do you mean current date or file creation date?

Comment: Can you post the source code of your script?  How is the timestamp actually formatted? Can you folllow the StackOverflow posting guidelines?

Answer (score 1):

to insert the time stamp of the file itself into the original file name, as well as preserving that timestamp in the target file, the following works in GNU environments:

```
file="/some/dir/path-to-file.xxx";
cp -p "$file" "${file%.*}-$(date -r"$file" '+%Y%m%d-%H%M%S').${file##*.}"
```

Adding proper use of the basename(1) command into the mix would allow you to copy the file into a different directory.

It's more challenging to do this outside of GNU/Linux environments and you have to start visiting languages like awk, perl, python, even php, to replace the  `date -r` command.

Answer (score 0):

Suppose

```
var="/path/to/filename.ext" #path is optional
```

Do

```
var1="${var##*/}
cp "$var" "/path/to/new/directory/${var1%.*}$(date +%s).${var1##*.}"
```

For more on `${var%.*}` & `${var##*.}` , see [[ shell parameter expansion ]](https://www.gnu.org/software/bash/manual/html_node/Shell-Parameter-Expansion.html).

---

date manpage says :

```
%s seconds since 1970-01-01 00:00:00 UTC
```

Answer (score 0):

```
file="file_to_copy"
cp $file "/path/to/dest/$file"`stat --printf "%X" $file`
```

You can look at the manual page of stat (`man 1 stat`) to choose the appropriate timestamp for your needs (creation, last access etc.)

In this example, I chose %X which means `time of last access, seconds since Epoch`